# Why local-intercept for PWA doesn't work?

Tags: reactjs, progressive-web-apps, magento2

I use Magento2 for a PWA with react as CMS and Venia-ui as theme, and I'm totally new to this. I want to change the link of cart page with a local-intercept.js but when I go to the link, the page is not displayed.

[The page not displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PoKtv.png)

My package.json

```
"pwa-studio": {
    "targets": {
      "intercept": "./src/targets/local-intercept"
    }
}
```

My local-intercept.js

```
function localIntercept(targets) {
    targets.of('@magento/venia-ui').routes.tap(routes => [
        ...routes,
        {
            name: "Cart",
            pattern: "/cart",
            exact: true,
            path: "../overrides/venia-ui/lib/code/CartPage"
        },
        {
            name: "CreateAccountPage",
            pattern: "/create-account",
            exact: true,
            path: "../overrides/venia-ui/lib/code/CreateAccountPage"
        }
    ]);
}
module.exports = localIntercept;
```

I already tried to display the cart page and it works.
The path to access the cart page on my local-intercept is ok.

I want to fix the bug of the cart page before the "create account page". Maybe it will fix the bug for this two pages at the same time

- @magento/pwa-buildpack: 7.0.0
- @magento/venia-ui: 5.0.0
- react: 16.9.0

Comment: Hey, did you manage to make it work? I am having the exact same issue. And the answer below does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this and return routes,

```
module.exports = targets => {
targets.of('@magento/venia-ui').routes.tap(routes => {
    routes.push({
        name: 'Login',
        pattern: '/customer/login',
        path: require.resolve(
            '../overrides/venia-ui/components/LogIn/LogIn.js'
        )
    }),
    routes.push({
        name: "Register",
        pattern: '/customer/register',
        path: require.resolve(
            '../overrides/venia-ui/components/LogIn/Register/RegisterUser.js'
        )
    }),
    routes.push({
        name: "Forget Password",
        pattern: '/customer/forgetpassword',
        path: require.resolve(
            '../overrides/venia-ui/components/ForgotPassword/forgotPassword.js'
        )
    }),
    routes.push({
        name: "Customer Profile",
        pattern: '/account-profile',
        path: require.resolve(
            '../overrides/venia-ui/components/AccountProfilePage/accountProfilePage.js'
        )
    });
    return routes;
});};
```

And no need to give like,

```
"intercept": "./src/targets/local-intercept"
```

You can give,

```
"intercept": "src/targets/local-intercept"
```

Comment: This example code has many syntax errors, I guess this is just to give an idea of what to do. I actually can't make this work, the routes keep throwing the 404 custom page.